# Trap "break" not working while read command is being called

Tags: bash, read, trap, sigint

I have this bash-written hangman game for a school project, and currently I am trying to replace the ctrl-c exit command for a while loop break, so the user goes back from the actual game to the categories selection menu.

The code I am currently using is:

```
trap "break" SIGINT
```

and inside the while loop:

```
read CHAR
```

Everything works fine when a text is printed in the loop and also when the sleep command is running, but when the algorithm is at the read command, pressing ctrl-c just inputs "^C" on the console.

Comment: Please update your post to show all the steps you have taken. Include as much of the script as possible to help troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 3):

> If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes.

That is the reason why the `read` is not interrupted.

The `^C` is not printed by the shell but by the terminal due to the setting `echoctl`. If you execute `stty -echoctl` then it does not appear.